# Access QWizardPage created by Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am using Qt Designer to create a QWizardPage.

I have imported the file into Qt Creator and it runs fine so far (I can build the project and run the wizard just fine)

Now I need to reimplement the `isComplete` function but I an unable to understand how to do it. The pages are named `wizardPage{,1,2_1,_2}`. I would like to know whats the best way to reimplement the `isComplete()` function now.

Comment: can't you use the `completeChanged()` signal and hook it up to a slot (function) for processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to overload the [`isComplete()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwizardpage.html#isComplete) function of a [`QWizardPage`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwizardpage.html), you need to create the `QWizardPage` yourself.  Basically, layout a form -- like you would a dialog -- for only the page you want.  Create a class for that page.  This class inherits from `QWizardPage` and reimplements `isComplete()` for whatever checks you desire.  Now in your wizard, find where you want the page to be.  Delete all the widgets on it, then right-click and select `Promote Widget...`.  Enter your class name and the path to the header file.  Now when you compile, it should use an instance of your class for that page, including your override for `isComplete()`.

Comment: which means I would have to recreate everything again, but create it as QWizardPages instead of a normal QWizard?

Comment: @Hiemanshu Sharma: Yes.  However, it's not really that difficult for most setups.  You can open the current wizard and the new page widgets in the same instance of Qt Designer, then cut the widgets from the wizard and paste them into the page.

Comment: Sounds doable. Shouldn't really take that much time yes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to ask but return false from [isComplete()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwizardpage.html#isComplete) if you want to disable "Next" button of the wizard.

When you want to enable the "Next" button emit [completeChanged()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwizardpage.html#completeChanged) signal and return true.

The default implementation already returns true. So you may not even need to override this method.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. I want to implement isComplete() but how I access the pages I created using Qt Designer. (all the code is in the header generated by compiling the ui file)