# In PyQt5, using Qt Designer, how can I initialize a Wizard page to use information from previous pages?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have created a wizard in Qt Designer. I would like one of the pages to be populated with variable information, depending on what data was provided in previous wizard pages. From the Qt documentation, I see the information to initialize with C++, but I can't determine how to do it with Python.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408481/access-qwizardpage-created-by-qt-designer) but again, it's C++. I tried using the Promote Widget... command in Qt Designer, but it asks for the class and header, so again, I don't see how to use it for Python.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64817652/how-to-properly-initialize-a-qwizard-page) for Python, but it appears to be a manually created Qt Wizard, rather than one created with Qt Designer.

I tried using `self.wizardPage.initialize()`, which should work, but I couldn't figure out how to "populate" that method without rewriting the entire class for that page. And assuming I did that, I couldn't figure out how to insert that new class into the wizard.

I looked at created a new Wizard Page in my Python code, with the intention of overriding the existing page in the Wizard, but had no success with that. Do I just have to hand-code the wizard and forego Qt Designer?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: It completely depends on *what* you need to "initialize". If you need simple things, such as to disable a button when a checkbox is toggled, use the internal signal/slot tool of designer, otherwise you need to do it by code, and the designer ui is only used as a "skeleton".

Comment: You have 2 tasks: 1) Create a custom QWizardPage where initialize method is overrided and as you already pointed out there is already a post that covers this topic, 2) promote a widget (the QWizardPage) written in python in Qt Designer and I have already added several posts that implement that logic

Comment: @musicamante That was actually useful information. Thanks.

Comment: Self-answer: Everything else was too complicated, I discovered. Simply using `self.button(QWizard.NextButton).clicked.connect(self.desired_method)` keeps everything within the Wizard, with all object accessible. Referencing the precursor objects to populate the wizard page works just fine.